# Android: Merge-Tag doesn't work with fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm a beginner in using fragments. Is it possible to have a layout like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <include layout="@layout/waiting_dialog"/>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_tile"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <include layout="@layout/no_entries"/>      
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

and use it in the fragments' onCreateView like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false); 
    return view;
}
```

There's always the following error:

```
07-11 09:53:47.608: E/AndroidRuntime(5602): android.view.InflateException: \
  <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
```

How to handle this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351391/281545) it is not possible.

What I did was altogether drop the "root layout" (see `battery_details.xml`). So I create a fragment layout for my  MonitorActivity :

```
public class MonitorActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitor);
    }
}
```

where the layout is :

```
<!-- activity_monitor.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MonitorActivity" >
    <fragment android:name="di.k23b.hw3.fragments.MonitorDetailsFragment"
            android:id="@+id/monitor_details"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="di.k23b.hw3.fragments.MonitorPrefsFragment"
            android:id="@+id/monitor_preferences"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in MonitorDetailsFragment class :

```
public class MonitorDetailsFragment extends Fragment {  
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.battery_details, container, false); // NEVER TRUE !
    }
}
```

where the `battery_details.xml` (created in `res/layout`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/batteryTextHealth"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="BATTERRRYYY"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" >
</TextView>
```

Works. So maybe you can edit the layout you use the fragments, add the `<LinearLayout>` there and just put the elements of the `<LinearLayout>` directly into the layout you use in the `OnCreateView` - dropping the merge tags

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already place your fragment somewhere in your activity. (Am I right ?)
That's why he claimed to already have a parent.

If you really want to reuse it then you have to detach it from its parent in its existing view hierarchy.

When inflating a layout starting with a `<merge />`, you must specify a parent `ViewGroup` and you must also set `attachToRoot` to `true`.