# Can you use the merge tag with fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, merge, android-fragments

If I use the `merge` tag as the parent tag for my fragment's layout, I run into two issues:

- first, in `onCreateView()`, if I specify NOT to attach to root, I get the error:

  `android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true`
- and if I DO attach to root, I get the error:

  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

I found a nice answer to another question here saying that the fragment library will automatically attach the child to the parent view group you specify in replace.  The suggestion was that you needed to therefore set `attachToRoot` to `false`.  For the `merge` tag, it's required.

Is it possible to get around either of these rules to use the `merge` tag for a fragment's layout?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> Is it possible to get around either of these rules to use the merge
>   tag for a fragment's layout?

No. As you already seen, when you inflate a layout file which has the `merge` tag as its root you **must** attach it to a valid parent `ViewGroup`. Attaching it to the container in the `onCreateView` is incorrect as the `View` returned by that method will be added by the framework.

You could always just create a wrapper layout in the `onCreateView` method to which to attach the inflated layout(and return this wrapper layout), but this will make the `merge` tag optimization useless as you could add the wrapper layout in the xml layout file from the start:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(getActivity()); // for example
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_with_merge_as_root, wrapper, true);
     return wrapper;
}
```

Comment: So the `android.view.InflateException: can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true` is because of `attachToRoot=false` (the ViewGroup root is valid) ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Yes, because for `false` the inflated layout will not be added to the `ViewGroup` and that is exactly what the `merge` tag requires. Also, I think the same exception will be thrown if you use `true` for `attachToRoot` but with a `null` `ViewGroup` for the second parameter(meaning no parent to which to attach the inflated layout).

Comment: Thanks - how annoying - same error message for 2 situations. Concerning `merge` and `fragments` you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15315289/281545) of interest

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Well You've gone with the only option, loosing the `merge` tag in the layout inflated as the fragment's View. Also as fragments should be designed as independent units a `merge` tag maybe isn't such a good idea in the first place anyway.

Comment: Thanks - I also achieved a flat hierarchy - I was a bit surprised I could just add a `TextView` - but it works :)

Comment: Android just screws it up here.

Comment: This defeats the entire purpose of using the merge tag. The point is to get rid of extra ViewGroup layers in the layout hierarchy.