# Optimize layout during Fragment replacement in FragmentActivity

Tags: android

I tried to replace a `Fragment` in `FragmentActivity` run-time.

### fragment_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

### MyFragmentActivity.java

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity);
    }

    // Will be called by AsyncTaskLoader's onLoadFinished.
    public void selectActiveContent() {
        // MyFragment's top level is LinearLayout
        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();         

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

However, I realize the outcome is not optimized.

[image]

I realize the `FrameLayout` supplied through my own `fragment_activity.xml`, is being attached to another parent `FrameLayout`.

Instead of

```
FrameLayout
    FrameLayout
        LinearLayout
            LinearLayout
            ListView
```

I wish to have

```
FrameLayout
    LinearLayout
        LinearLayout
        ListView
```

May I know how I can achieve so? Is it possible I can have a `fragment_activity.xml` without a `ViewGroup` (FrameLayout) ?

Answer (score 0):

While the [`<merge>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#merge-element) element was specifically designed for removing useless levels of view hierarchy, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351391/1676363), you cannot use merge tags in Fragments and you must instead use a ViewGroup root view as you noticed, the lightest weight (i.e., fastest to render) being a FrameLayout.

Comment: No luck. I get `<merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot`. I google, seems like I still need to manually create a FrameLayout in my code and attach to it?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng- you're right. As the layout generated by a Fragment's onCreateView is attached by the framework (and not attached upon inflation as a `<merge>` tag requires, I think you're stuck with a FrameLayout.