# Android flipview in a fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, flipview

Am trying to make a ui with flipview as in [this](https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView?files=1) tutorial. IThe tutorial deals with activities, but i want it in fragments case. That ie, the flip effect as well as its parent is a fragment. When i use activity it works, but on using fragment,only the empty textview shows up. Can anyone help me with this?

This is some part of the code

page.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff3333" >
  <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/banner"
    android:id="@+id/head"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/des"
  android:textSize="30dp"
  android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_news_feed :

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:flipview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
      <se.emilsjolander.flipview.FlipView
        android:id="@+id/flip_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        flipview:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.excel.excelapp.fragment.NewsFeedFragment" >
      </se.emilsjolander.flipview.FlipView>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Empty!"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
      </merge>
```

NewsFeedFragment.java

```
public class NewsFeedFragment extends Fragment implements NewsFlipAdapter.Callback, FlipView.OnFlipListener, FlipView.OnOverFlipListener{

    private FlipView mFlipView;
    private NewsFlipAdapter mAdapter;

    int i=0,no_of_items=7;

    public NewsFeedFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, wrapper, true);
        setUpView(view);
        return wrapper;
    }

    private void setUpView(View view) {
        mFlipView = (FlipView) view.findViewById(R.id.flip_view);
        mAdapter = new NewsFlipAdapter(getActivity());
        mAdapter.setCallback(this);
        mFlipView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mFlipView.setOnFlipListener(this);
        mFlipView.peakNext(false);
        mFlipView.setOverFlipMode(OverFlipMode.RUBBER_BAND);
        mFlipView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
        mFlipView.setOnOverFlipListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageRequested(int page) {
        mFlipView.smoothFlipTo(page);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFlippedToPage(FlipView v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("pageflip", "Page: " + position);
        if(position > mFlipView.getPageCount()-3 && mFlipView.getPageCount()<30){
            mAdapter.addItems(5);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOverFlip(FlipView v, OverFlipMode mode,
                           boolean overFlippingPrevious, float overFlipDistance,
                           float flipDistancePerPage) {
        Log.i("overflip", "overFlipDistance = "+overFlipDistance);
    }
```

NewsFlipAdapter.java

```
public class NewsFlipAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public interface Callback {
        public void onPageRequested(int page);
    }

    static class Item {
        static long id = 0;
        long mId;

        public Item() {
            mId = id++;
        }

        long getId() {
            return mId;
        }
    }


    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Callback callback;
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public NewsFlipAdapter(Context context) {

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


    }

    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return items.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, parent, false);
            holder.heading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.des);
            holder.header = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.head);
            //  holder.firstPage = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.first_page);
            //  holder.lastPage = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.last_page);
            //  holder.firstPage.setOnClickListener(this);
            //  holder.lastPage.setOnClickListener(this);
            //  convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView heading;
        ImageView header;
        TextView description;


    }

    /*  @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          switch(v.getId()){
              case R.id.first_page:
                  if(callback != null){
                      callback.onPageRequested(0);
                  }
                  break;
              case R.id.last_page:
                  if(callback != null){
                      callback.onPageRequested(getCount()-1);
                  }
                  break;
          }
      }*/
    public void addItems(int amount) {
        TextView text;
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            items.add(new Item());

        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItemsBefore(int amount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            items.add(0, new Item());
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that is the reason, but`public Object getItem(int position) { return position; }` looks wrong. Shouldn't that be something like `public Object getItem(int position) { return items.get(position); }`?

Comment: I seem to remember that `merge` is not recommeded for fragment layouts. And another thing you might try in NewsFlipAdapter.getView is attaching the inflated view too parent: `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, parent, true)`;

Comment: @Sascha  tried that ..Still not working. Instead of merge wht to do.?

Comment: anyone has a way out?? is there another way to use instead of merge?

Comment: Just try to replace `merge` with e.g. `LinearLayout`

Comment: @Sascha : thanks a lott :) this is the answer. Please write it as an answer so that i can tick it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a 100 % sure about the following explanation, so please correct me if I am wrong.

The `<merge>` tag merges the inflated layout with it's parent view. 
It generally doesn't seem to sit well with fragments as explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348455/can-you-use-the-merge-tag-with-fragments).

So try to replace `merge` with `LinearLayout` in your fragment_newsfeed_layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:flipview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
      <se.emilsjolander.flipview.FlipView
        android:id="@+id/flip_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        flipview:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.excel.excelapp.fragment.NewsFeedFragment" >
      </se.emilsjolander.flipview.FlipView>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Empty!"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
      </LinearLayout>
```