# Is there any way to optimized the resultant layout when adding a Fragment to an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

It is very common to add a `Fragment` to an `Activity`.

Let's say I have the following `Activity`'s layout and `Fragment`'s layout.

### activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_from_activity" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_from_fragment" />
```

If I add the fragment to activity

```
// Java code in Activity. To add Fragment to Activity.
this.webViewFragment = WebViewFragment.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_from_activity, this.webViewFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

The resultant layout (I'm using Tools -> Layout Inspector in Android Studio) would look as following.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_from_activity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_from_fragment" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I was wondering, is it possible to eliminate the redundant `content_from_activity` , and have the following outcome when adding `Fragment` to `Activity`?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_from_fragment" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It seems that it is not possible to use `<merge>` for `Fragment.

[Can you use the merge tag with fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348455/can-you-use-the-merge-tag-with-fragments)

I was wondering, do you have any technique, to optimized the resultant layout when adding a `Fragment` to an `Activity`?

Comment: I have a question just out of curiosity, and sorry if that sounds stupid, how did you get the resultant layout since the fragment is added programatically ?

Comment: I'm using Tools -> Layout Inspector in Android Studio